# Can I replace a spiral window balance with a constant force balance?

Tags: windows

I have old vinyl windows from '79 that currently have 24" long 5/8" diameter spiral balances.  They have the red tip.  Can I replace these with constant force balances?

Answer (score 2):

As a manufacturer of all three types of window, balances, [Caldwell](http://www.caldwellmfgco.com/default.asp) are uniquely positioned to have insight into you question.

Does this look like your balance?  Its [Caldwells' EZ Lift series](http://www.caldwellmfgco.com/spiral_balances_ezlift.asp)
[image]

Unfortunately, their constant force balances require a much different mechanism, so a new window would likely be needed.
[image]